# Entity Framework 4.1 Code First - Unable to remove a relationship between two entities

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I have a Supplier entity, each Supplier object may reference another Supplier object as its 'parent'.

```
public class Supplier
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Supplier Parent { get; set; }
}
```

This all works as expected until I attempt to remove the relationship, as in, this supplier no longer has a parent. I can change it from null to a particular supplier and I can set it to a different supplier but setting it to null is not persisted after SaveChanges().

```
supplier.Parent = null;
```

The foreign key 'ParentId' in the Supplier table is set as nullable. Explicitly defining the relationship doesn't help.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Supplier>().HasOptional(s => s.Parent).WithMany();
```

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just found another place in my code where I do the exact same thing (that works) and found this;

```
// Must access property (trigger lazy-loading) before we can set it to null (Entity Framework bug!!!)
var colour = modelItem.Colour;
modelItem.Colour = null;
```

Did the same in the new code and it all works.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of just `modelBuilder.Entity<Supplier>().HasOptional(s => s.Parent).WithMany();` use the following `modelBuilder.Entity<Supplier>().HasOptional(s => s.Parent).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x=>x.ParentId);`
Otherwise it has no idea what the foreign key's name is

Comment: We don't use foreign key properties i.e ParentId

Comment: I had the same problem and Stephen is right, you have to define a Foreign Key. See Arthur Vickers' post here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adonetefx/thread/35e7438b-ec1f-4d1f-bca0-539ccfb9abb1/

Comment: "Is there any good reason not to?"

I'm not sure why I would? I haven't done anywhere else in the domain and I'm sure there's nothing that says you have to. The relationship is correctly determined by EF and works except when you try to remove the relationship as if it thinks the foreign key field it has created is not nullable. We have a sizeable domain already and nowhere are foreign keys defined and it works. Something is not right if I have to do it just in this scenario.

Comment: The solution was to access the property before setting it to null.